# Show that $x^2-x+1$ divides $x^{20}+x^{10}+1$

Tags: polynomials

Respected all.

Please help me on the following.

we need to prove that $x^2-x+1$ divides $x^{20}+x^{10}+1$.

I tried several ways, but in vain. I am not sure if the question is correct or not but let me assure you, the question has been quoted exactly as it is. What I tried was the following:

Now $x^2-x+1=(x-\sigma_1)(x-\sigma_2)$ where $\sigma_1=\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}, \sigma_2=\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}, \sigma_1^2=\sigma_2, \sigma_2^2=-\sigma_1$.

If $f(\sigma_k)=0$ for $k=1,2$ then we will be done. But I could not show this last part. Each and every time I am getting non-zero answer.

What am I supposed to do ? Is there any other way to solve it ?

Comment: Hint: $\sigma_k^3=-1$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint : if $r$ is a root of $x^2-x+1$, then $r^3=(-1),r^6=1,r^{10}=\ldots, r^{20}=\ldots$

Comment: It seems to me there must be an easy way to derive that the third power of the roots of this polynomial are -1 without calculating those roorts explicitly, however I can't see it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: @dimpol $0 = (r+1)(r^2 - r + 1) = r^3 + 1$

Comment: @dimpol If $r^2-r+1=0$ then $r^3+1=(r+1)(r^2-r+1)=0$ hence $r^3=-1$, qed.

Comment: As simple as I expected, thank you both for your extraordinary fast answers!

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any other way to solve it?

The right way to compute with the roots has already be explained, but surely just **doing the long polynomial division** also counts as "any other way". Eighteen steps in the division is not that much.

This even gives you the quotient explicitly:
$$ x^{20}+x^{10}+1 = \\(x^{18}+x^{17}-x^{15}-x^{14}+x^{12}+x^{11}-x^9+x^7+x^6-x^4-x^3+x+1)(x^2-x+1) $$

Comment: Yep; took me just two or three minutes, working in bed on a scrap of paper supported on a book. Most likely misses the intended point of the problem, but it certainly works!

Answer (score 1):

$\sigma_2$ and $\sigma_1$ are more commonly known as $-j$ and $-\bar j=-j^2$ respectively, , where $j$ and $j^2$ are the non-real third roots of unity.

Hence $\sigma_1^{6}=\sigma_2^{6}=1$, so that 
$$\sigma_1^{20}+\sigma_1^{10}+1=\sigma_1^2+\sigma_1^4+1=j^4+j^8+1=j+j^2+1=0,$$
and similarly for $\sigma_2$.

Comment: $j$ is probably not a good name to use for that constant, because some textbooks (chiefly aimed at electrical engineering, it seems) use that for the imaginary unit.

Comment: I know, but it's a traditional notation in maths. For me it's purely a maths problem. I also might say $\sigma_1$ is often used for a permutation in group theory…

Comment: Hmm, I've never seen $j$ used for this -- mostly $\zeta$ and $\xi$ for roots of unity.

Comment: @HenningMakholm or $\omega$.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the roots of $x^2-x+1$ do not equal $-1$ and

$$(x+1)(x^2-x+1)=x^3+1=0$$ yields the two complex cube roots of $-1$.

On another hand, for these roots $x^{10}=(x^3)^3x=-x\ne 1$ while

$$(x^{10}-1)(x^{20}+x^{10}+1)=x^{30}-1=(-1)^{10}-1=0$$ so that they are also roots of $x^{20}+x^{10}+1$.

---

Or more directly, $x^{20}+x^{10}+1=(x^3)^6x^2+(x^3)^3x+1=x^2-x+1=0$.

Comment: The direct one is more perfect and beautiful. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other way to solve it ?

Since all the good answers have been posted already, here is a less orthodox one. The problem is equivalent to proving that if $x^2 - x + 1=0$ then $x^{20}+x^{10}+1 = 0$, which can be rewritten as:

$$x+ \frac{1}{x} = 1 \quad \implies \quad x^{10} + \frac{1}{x^{10}} = -1$$

Consider the sequence $a_n = x^n + 1 \,/\, x^n$. Obviously $a_0=2$ and $a_1=x + 1\,/\, x=1$ then:

$$a_1 \cdot a_n = \left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right) \cdot \left(x^n+\frac{1}{x^n}\right) = x^{n+1} + \frac{1}{x^{n+1}} + x^{n-1} + \frac{1}{x^{n-1}}=a_{n+1} + a_{n-1}$$

thus $a_{n+1} = a_n - a_{n-1}$. It follows that $(a_n \mid n \ge 0) = (2, 1, -1, -2, -1, 1, 2, 1, \cdots)$ is a periodic sequence with period $6$, so $\;x^{10}+1/x^{10}=a_{10}=a_4=-1\;$ which concludes the proof.

Comment: Remarkably astonishing and fascinating result

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have many tools at your disposal, then remember $\Bbb Z[X]$ is a Euclidean ring division and performs the corresponding operation. This has to give zero residu. In fact you get
$$x^{20}+x^{10}+1=(x^2-x+1)(x^{18}+x^{17}-x^{15}-x^{14}+x^{12}+x^{11}-x^9+x^7+x^6-x^4-x^3+x+1)$$ 
Not very elegant but it is safe and quite elemental.

Comment: Correct, but posted already (http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1995844/291201).

Comment: In any case I have not seen before this link. I hope you believe me, don't you?

Comment: My comment was meant for information, not faulting. I should have probably made that more clear..

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$x^2-x+1|x^3+1$$
and
$$x^3+1|x^{20}-x^2 \\
x^3+1|x^{10}+x$$